# How to write regex to check for specified password

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that checks if string contains 6 or more signs including 1 or more special sign [^0-9a-zA-Z\s] and 1 or more [0-9a-zA-Z].
Spent like 2h and not getting any closer :/

Comment: Without examples to test against, it is almost impossible.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is of some help:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,13}$
```

Password expresion that requires one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit, 6-13 length, and no spaces.

Matches:

```
1agdH*$# | 1agdC*$# | 1agdB*$#
```

Non-Matches:

```
wyrn%@*&amp;$# f | mbndkfh782 | BNfhjdhfjd&amp;*)%#$)
```

This is based on the Regex Lib entry [here](http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=157)

Comment: {4,8} restricts the length from 4-8 length not 6-13 length

Answer (score 0):

Taking the style of Hasson's answer . . .

```
grep -P '^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9\s])(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{6}'
```

- 6 or more chars (regexp not ended with $)
- 1 or more special char (?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z\s])
- 1 or more (?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z])
- no whitespace (?!.*\s)

Some test data, NO match:

```
password
pa5sword
pa5sWord
pa5sWord
password
test
1agdA
1agd
wyrn%@*&amp;$# f
mbndkfh782
t1*$
```

Some test data, YES match:

```
pa5*Word
pa5*Word
pa5*Word1
pa5*Wor 
1agdA*
1agdA*$
1agdA*$#
1agdA*$#1
1agdA*$#12
1agdA*$#123
1agdA*$#a
1agdA*$#ab
1agdA*$#abc
1agdA*$#abcd
BNfhjdhfjd&amp;*)%#$)
```